# SSO/Authentication between Joomla and a Flex Application!

Tags: apache-flex, joomla, single-sign-on

I am developing an application in Adobe Flex. This application is to be hosted on a Joomla Website. I want to achieve Single Sign On between my Joomla website and this Flex Application.

The Users log in using the default Joomla Mechanisms however I want the username as well as some other details about the user inside my Flex Application.

Thanks in advance for any help in this regard.
Amitesh.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass flashvars to your flex application written from server side by joomla.